# Assigning a variable to an object in Freemarker templates

Tags: templates, freemarker

I am trying to avoid repeatedly refering to objects like this:

```
${outter.inner.assignThisGuy.field1}
```

and would like to refer to lowest level, i.e.

```
${assignThisGuy.field1}
```

This will help me remove repeated null checks and make my template tidier.  I'm not sure if this is possible. All the notes refer to assigning a variable to a type like ?string, ?date, etc.

When I try to do it I get an exception:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. thisGuy evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar
```

I have tried variations on:

```
[#assign thisGuy = "${outter.inner.assignThisGuy}" ]
```

I just want to be sure this is not possible before some of my lines become massive in length!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, like this:

```
<#assign thisGuy = outter.inner.assignThisGuy>
...
${thisGuy.field1}
```